# Is the name->value pair of an attribute in XML considered to be two nodes, interpreted by XPATH?

Tags: xml, xpath, datamodel, xmlnode

The following article http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JAXPXSLT3.html says that XPATH considers the following to be nodes:

- Root
- Element
- Text
- Attribute
- Comment
- Processing instruction
- Namespace

What I want to know is whether an attribute 'id' and its value '2' are considered to be two different nodes? e.g. `<name id="2">text</name>`

Or are text nodes just the 'data' http://www.w3.org/XML/Datamodel.html between elements? My intuition tells me that XPATH would consider there to be 4 nodes in this example - the 'name' element, the attribute 'id' the text value '2' and the text value 'text'.

Comment: I beleive it would be three. I don't think the value of an attribute is considered a different node. The attribute, key and value together, is a single node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An attribute node has a name and a value. They are not separate nodes. The following XML:

```
<name id="2">text</name>
```

...represents three nodes: 1) an element whose name is `name`; 2) a child node of `name` that is a text node; 3) an attribute node whose name is `id` and whose value is `2`.

From [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#attribute-nodes):

> An attribute node has an expanded-name and a string-value.

And later:

> An attribute node has a string-value. The string-value is the
>   normalized value as specified by the XML Recommendation [XML]. An
>   attribute whose normalized value is a zero-length string is not
>   treated specially: it results in an attribute node whose string-value
>   is a zero-length string.

Answer (score 1):

**The [string value](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#dt-string-value) of an attribute node is just a string -- it isn't a node itself**.

**Any string value of a node should not be confused with any text node**. A text node is a child of an element node and it itself has a string value.

Often the string value of a text node isn't the string we are presented with in the serialization of an XML document, for example in:

```
<t>M &amp; M</t>
```

the string value of the text node selected by `/*/text()` is not `"M &amp; M"`, it is:

```
M & M
```